# Backup Job with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, backup

I have a question about this code... what it should do is:
Start the program (Backup.vbs), window pops up asking if you want a full or an incremental backup, after you choose 1 or 2 it copies all files from a folder to a backup folder for a full backup, for the incremental it should create a folder with the date of the copy day, copy all the files that have been modified since the last full backup and copy them in that folder.

Could you please help me finish the code?

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, file
Dim pfadfull, pfadinc
Dim destfull, destinc
Dim datum
Dim windowname
Dim demofile, date1, date2
Dim strMsg,inp01,strFlag

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = true

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded)

Datum = date()
windowname = "DIAGNOSDATA AG Backup"

' Wahl ob Full oder Ink Backup
strMsg = "1.) Full Backup" & vbCR
strMsg = strMsg & "2.) Inkrementeller Backup" & vbCR
strMsg = strMsg & "Leer lassen um das Programm zu beenden." & vbCR

strFlag = False

Do While strFlag = False

inp01 = InputBox(strMsg,"DIAGNOSDATA AG Backup")

Select Case inp01
    Case "1"
        ' Full Backup
        pfadfull = inputbox("Geben Sie das Verzeichnis ein, welches Sie sichern moechten:", windowname, "C:\Users\")
        file.write pfadfull
        destfull = inputbox("Geben Sie den Speicherort ein, welcher fuer den Full Backup gebraucht wird:", windowname, "\\server\Backup\")
        file.write destfull
        destfull = destfull & datum
        FSO.CopyFolder pfadfull ,destfull, true
        MsgBox "Full Backup erfolgreich!", 64, windowname
        strFlag = True
    Case "2"
        ' Ink Backup
        pfadinc = inputbox("Geben Sie das Verzeichnis ein, welches Sie inkrementell sichern moechten:", windowname, "C:\Users\")
        file.write pfadinc
        destinc = inputbox("Geben Sie den Speicherort ein, welcher fuer den inkrementellen Backup gebraucht wird:", windowname, "\\server\Backup\")
        file.write destinc
        Set demofile = fso.GetFolder(pfadinc)
        date1 = demofile.DateLastModified
        for each date1 in demofile  
            If DateDiff("s", date1, date2) > 0 Then
                If DateDiff("n", date1, date2) > 0 Then
                    If DateDiff("h", date1, date2) > 0 Then
            file.Copy destinc
                    Else
                    End If
                Else
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Next
        msgbox "hi", 64, windowname
        strFlag = True
    Case ""
        MsgBox "Aufwiedersehen!", 64, windowname
        strFlag = True
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Bitte weahlen Sie 1 oder 2 aus.", 64, windowname
End Select

Loop

Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: What specific problem do you have with your code, i.e. what isn't working as desired?

Comment: For the incremental part (after a full backup), i would suggest you to use `robocopy.exe` with options to only list output (`/L`) with destination folder as the "previous Full backup folder name", redirect the output to a txt file then process it - look for `New File`, `Newer`. Incremental backups afterwards are a lot more work. As you need to combine changes from previous full backup to all previous incremental folders.